# React + Axios: Rest API while loop all posts (with info from Response headers)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, axios, rest, request-headers

So far I have a Axios get request for a WP REST API authenticated route. This renders fine the maximum of 100 posts per request, also fetches the response header which shows that there are actually 894 posts and 9 pages in total:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      posts: [],
      error: "",
      items: [],
      result: [],
    };
  }

  createMarkup = (data) => ({
    __html: data,
  });
  componentDidMount() {
    const wordPressSiteURL = clientConfig.siteUrl;
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const result = [];

    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      axios
        .get(`${wordPressSiteURL}/wp-json/kbs/v1/tickets?per_page=100`, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
          },
        })
        .then((result) => {
          let totalPosts = result.headers["x-wp-total"];
          let totalPages = result.headers["x-wp-totalpages"];

          console.log(
            `there are ${totalPosts} posts divided in ${totalPages} pages`
          );
          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            items: result.data,
          });
        });
    }); // this state
  }
```

**How could I loop dynamically through with the response header knowledge so I would have all the posts on the same page?** Note that loading time is not an issue in context of this application.

It seems I'd have to reimplement the same get request with a while loop and include a variable of `$totalPages` as the page query parameter `'?page=$totalPages'` but it would be great if some advice could point me in the right direction how to structure this code here as getting even this far has been quite a challenge for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks good! From what you've said it sounds like you're exactly on track - you need to use a loop to keep requesting more data while you're under the page limit. You could use soemthing like this (obviously this is untested but hopefully gets you on the right track):

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const wordPressSiteURL = clientConfig.siteUrl;
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

    let posts = [];
    let hasMorePages = true;

    for (let pageNumber = 0; hasMorePages; pageNumber++) {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('per_page', 100);
        if (pageNumber > 0) {
            params.append('page', pageNumber);
        }
        
        const url = `${wordPressSiteURL}/wp-json/kbs/v1/tickets?${params}`;
        const result = await axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
            },
        });

        posts = [...posts, result.data];

        const postsOnThisPage = result.data.length;
        const totalPages = result.headers["x-wp-totalpages"];
        console.log(`Loaded page ${pageNumber}/${totalPages} which contained ${postsOnThisPage} posts.`)
        
        hasMorePages = postsOnThisPage > 0 && pageNumber < totalPages;
    }

    this.setState({
        loading: false,
        posts,
    });
}
```

Note: you may as well set the value of `loading` to `true` in your construtor since the first thing the component will do when it mounts is start loading. That will save you one extra state change (which saves you one extra render).

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        loading: true,
        posts: [],
        error: "",
        items: [],
        result: [],
    };
}
```